# Table or view does not exist when opening cursor?

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g, cursor

I have a procedure that identifies each locked
account that was locked because of invalid login attempts. However the sp is creating with compilation errors: "ORA-00942: table does not exist". If I run the select statement by itself it works fine but within the sp. Can anyone help?

```
Create or replace PROCEDURE IdentifyLockedAccounts(p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
BEGIN
OPEN p_recordset FOR SELECT USERNAME FROM DBA_USERS WHERE ACCOUNT_STATUS = 'LOCKED' OR ACCOUNT_STATUS = 'LOCKED(TIMED)';
END IdentifyLockedAccounts;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your schema probably has SELECT privilege on DBA_USERS via some role (SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE for instance) - that is why you are able to run it via SQL client.

Roles are not enabled during the compilation of plsql/views therefore you have to grant SELECT ON DBA_USERS directly to schema to be able to use it in stored procedure.

```
GRANT SELECT ON DBA_USERS to YOURSCHEMA;
```